# Derivative with respect to vector of product of two functions of the vector

Tags: derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

I am struggling with the following derivative. Let $\pmb{x} \in  \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a vector, $\pmb{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ another vector that is a function of $\pmb{x}$, and $\pmb{g}$ and $\pmb{h}$ two functions returning vectors. I aim to obtain the following derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \pmb{x}}
\left( \pmb{g}(\pmb{y})^{\top} \otimes \pmb{I} \right)\pmb{h}(\pmb{x}). 
$$
My thoughts were that this would involve a combination of the sum and chain rule. E.g., first take the sum-rule with the left and right-hand part. But then $\left( \pmb{g}(\pmb{y})^{\top} \otimes \pmb{I} \right)$ takes the form of a matrix and I am quite lost. I expect that taking a differential form is needed, but I don't really understand how to do these properly yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define some new matrices 
$$\eqalign{
H &= {\rm Mat}(h) \implies h = {\rm vec}(H) \cr
J &= \frac{\partial h}{\partial x},\quad
 K = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y},\quad
 L = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \cr
}$$
Write the vector function and find its differential and gradient in terms of these new variables.
$$\eqalign{
 w &= (g^T\otimes I)h = Hg \cr
dw
 &= (g^T\otimes I)\,dh + H\,dg \cr
 &= \Big((g^T\otimes I)J + HKL\Big)\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}
 &= (g^T\otimes I)J + HKL \cr
}$$
Knowing nothing about the nature of the vector functions $(g,h,y)$ this is as far as we can go.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer and other answers you have given! I am writing a paper on maximum likelihood estimation on some multivariate models and this has all been really helpful for my work!